# php string echo behaving weirdly

Tags: php, string, printing, echo

The following is not printing anything and I have not yet found any explanations online:

```
<?php 
function aa() { 
  return "<w";
}

$r = aa();

echo $r;    
?>
```

No matter the kind of quotes I use. If I print any string not starting with < and followed by a character it prints correctly. Probably something on php.ini but, any ideas???

Comment: Have you tried "\<w" ? It escapes the "<" as a special char.

Comment: Just looking at the resulting webpage or the source? First impression is it's the start of an open-ended HTML tag.

Comment: Escaping it simply outputs the escape character. And this is the whole thing, stripped down to this simple php and viewing the result in chrome. so basically viewing the file at localhost/print.php which only has the code shown above

Comment: same thing happens on firefox though

Comment: So for instance. If I change the echo to "<" it prints < as expected, if i change it to "hello" it prints as expected, but changing it back to "<w" or even "<"."w" and I get no output whatsoever!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
 <?php 
function aa() { 
  return htmlspecialchars("<w");
}

$r = aa();

echo $r;    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do short_open_tag=On(to print html tag)/Off(not to print) in php.ini
I hope it will work for you.
Or you can do like

```
    echo "&rt"; //for right arrow and &lt for left arrow
```

Comment: this works as well, the &rt / &lt, the short_open_tag was already set to On, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the webpage that your PHP file generates looks like this:

```
<w
```

If you'd type this into a file test.html and open it in a webbrowser, you would as well not be able to see the string `<w`. This is because the HTML compiler of the webbrowser interprets the opening bracket `<` as an HTML tag. it can't understand this tag and thus prints nothing. if you want to print such a bracket, use HTML encoding:

```
&lt;
```

Comment: Not really! the problem started through an ajax load call in order to load some elements, the original method creates option tags for a select box. Avoiding the call to such method displays the whole page with an empty select box, when retrieving the <options> the output becomes absolutely blank. Exchanging the output of the method to anything like "<w" or "<o" gives the same behaviour. Maybe my bad for simplifying the question...

Comment: it doesn't matter under what circumstances your problem ocurrs, the reason is still the same: you *cannot* print < characters without escaping them. period. the answer that you accepted is doing the exact same thing as i said: it escapes < with &lt; by using the function htmlspecialchars(). so yes, my answer is correct.